# Simple echo program using sockets in C echoing incorrect message after the first run

Tags: c, sockets, echo

I am trying to learn the basic of network communication using sockets in C.  My client program takes in a message from the user, echoes it server side and back, and prints out the received message.  When I fire both of them up for the first time, they both work exactly as expected.  However, if I quit the client side and then fire it up again while keeping the server program running, my echoed messages become off by one.

I assumed it was because the last message is getting caught in the pipe or something, and after poking around, I saw that someone suggested to use `shutdown()` to flush out the pipe, but that doesn't seem to be working.  I also tried to zero out the buffers wherever I thought they may be lingering, but that didn't seem to help, either.

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT            12403
#define BUFFER_MAX      1024
#define BACKLOG_MAX     1024

int clientSocket;
int serverSocket;

void listening()
{
    while (1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
        socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &addressLength);
        if (clientSocket > -1)
        {
            printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddress.sin_port));
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int Count, char *Strings[])
{   
    struct sockaddr_in socketInfo;
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];

    //Create socket
    if ((serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Setting the linger option to off and resuse address option to on for testing
    int option = 0;
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &option, sizeof(option));
    option = 1;
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));

    //Initialize socket information
    bzero(&socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo));
    socketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketInfo.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    socketInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Assign a port number to the socket
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error binding socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Set socket to listen
    if (listen(serverSocket, BACKLOG_MAX) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error setting socket to listen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    listening();

    //Once first socket has been connected, begin echoing process
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        //Clear the buffer
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);

        //Echo back anything sent
        //Close connection and begin listening process again if the client disconnects
        int sendCheck;
        int readCheck;
        readCheck = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_MAX, 0);
        if (readCheck <= 0)
        {
            shutdown(clientSocket, SHUT_WR);
            close(clientSocket);
            sleep(1);
            listening();
        }
        sendCheck = send(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_MAX, 0);

        if (sendCheck <= 0)
        {
            shutdown(clientSocket, SHUT_WR);
            close(clientSocket);
            sleep(1);
            listening();
        }
        i++;
    }

    close(serverSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT            12403
#define LOCALHOST       "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFFER_MAX      1024

int socketStatus = 0;

void sigpipeHandler()
{
    perror("Connection to server terminated\n");
    socketStatus = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int mySocket;
    struct sockaddr_in socketInfo;
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];

    int count = 0;

    //Create socket
    if ((mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Get IP address of required host machine
    char* hostName = "<host name removed>";
    int portNumber = PORT;
    char* ipAddr = NULL;
    struct hostent* host = NULL;
    host = gethostbyname(hostName);
    ipAddr = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) host->h_addr_list[0]));

    //Initialize server information
    bzero(&socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo));
    socketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketInfo.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    if (inet_aton(ipAddr, (struct in_addr *)&socketInfo.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0)
    {
        perror("Error assigning IP address");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Set up sigpipe handler
    signal(SIGPIPE, sigpipeHandler);

    //Connect to server
    if (connect(mySocket, (struct sockaddr*)&socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error connecting");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Indicate that socket is OK
    socketStatus = 1;

    while(1)
    {
        if(!socketStatus) {shutdown(mySocket, SHUT_WR); break;}
        printf("Please enter a command.\n");
        char command[BUFFER_MAX];
        bzero(command, BUFFER_MAX);
        fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);

        send(mySocket, command, BUFFER_MAX, 0);

        //Get echoed message
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);
        recv(mySocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        printf("Echo [%d]:%s\n", ++count, buffer);
    }

    //Close socket
    close(mySocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your server will _only_ accept a single connection, process it, but then it either loops forever on the [now] obsolete socket or just terminates. That's because the server never loops on `accept` [as it should]. And, I don't mean how your doing it (e.g.) In your code, you want `while (1) { listening(); code_you_already_have_to_echo }`

Comment: start by `sendCheck = send(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_MAX, 0);`
**-->>** `sendCheck = send(clientSocket, buffer, readCheck, 0);`

Comment: @CraigEstey Upon moving the call to `listening()` to the very beginning of the `while (1)` loop directly after it, now I am getting the correct echo back on the first try during subsequent sessions.  Now however, on the client side, after the first command gets echoed back, I seem to get stuck in some kind of deadlock.  I can't enter any more commands after the first one.

Comment: You need multiple loops -- one inside the other. That will give you a simple one-client-at-a-time sequential server. What you probably *really* want is a server that can `accept` and service multiple connections at the same time. That will take either the use of `select` (to process multiple connections concurrently from a single thread) or the creation of a new dedicated thread per accepted connection.

Comment: Additionally your client code needs to check the return of "recv" call, so it can detect that the server has exited.

Comment: Good catch @TonyB .  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some cleanup on your server code and this seems to work.

For my testing, the client code is unchanged. But, as others have suggested, you should check the error codes from `send` and `recv`. Also, note that if you `ctrl-c` the server, the client will hang in the `fgets`, so it won't detect the server abort until you hit return after the prompt. Not a big deal, but I thought I'd mention it.

I also added a `fork` so you can have *multiple* clients talking to the same server instance simultaneously.

I tested this with two clients [in two `xterm` windows] talking with the single server instance.

I moved your echo code into a new function `docomm`. A small difference from your code is that *any* error from either `recv` or `send` breaks out of the loop and closes the connection. All connections from *new* clients are *guaranteed* to start with a `recv` call.

In your code, you would *not* always break out of the loop, but close the connection and call `listening` again. This would happen for *either* `send` or `recv`. If it happened on the *wrong* one, this *might* be the source of the problem you were having because you could do a `send` *before* a `recv` to a *new* client initially.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PORT            12403
#define BUFFER_MAX      1024
#define BACKLOG_MAX     1024

int clientSocket;
int serverSocket;
int forkflg = 1;

void listening()
{
    while (1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
        socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &addressLength);
        if (clientSocket > -1)
        {
            printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddress.sin_port));
            break;
        }
    }
}

void
docomm(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];

    //Once first socket has been connected, begin echoing process
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        //Clear the buffer
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);

        //Echo back anything sent
        //Close connection and begin listening process again if the client disconnects
        int sendCheck;
        int readCheck;

        readCheck = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_MAX, 0);
        if (readCheck <= 0)
            break;

        sendCheck = send(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_MAX, 0);
        if (sendCheck <= 0)
            break;

        i++;
    }

    printf("close\n");
    shutdown(clientSocket, SHUT_WR);
    close(clientSocket);
}

int main(int Count, char *Strings[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in socketInfo;

    //Create socket
    if ((serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Setting the linger option to off and resuse address option to on for testing
    int option = 0;
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &option, sizeof(option));
    option = 1;
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));

    //Initialize socket information
    bzero(&socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo));
    socketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketInfo.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    socketInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Assign a port number to the socket
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error binding socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //Set socket to listen
    if (listen(serverSocket, BACKLOG_MAX) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error setting socket to listen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    while (1) {
        listening();

        if (! forkflg) {
            docomm();
            continue;
        }

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            docomm();
            exit(0);
        }

        while (waitpid(0,NULL,WNOHANG) > 0);
    }

    close(serverSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Just from a glance: 1) Can I ask why you created a fork flag if you never change the value of it? Should it be changed somewhere?

I used `forkflg` so you can set it to zero (e.g. `int forkflg = 0;`) to run sequentially. Or, you could add some code and parse `argv` looking for an option (e.g. `-f`) to set/clear it [for testing/debug purposes]. For production code, you'd want `forkflg` to be set and could remove the flag and just do the fork case always [adjusting the code to match].

> Just tracing through the program mentally, it seems like the forking section will never be executed. Correct me where I'm wrong: after initially setting the socket to listen, the while loop will enter, and listening() will be called. Execution will halt in listening() until a connection is accepted.

Yes, that's true.

> Control will return to main, where docomm() gets called. Control stays in docomm() until the connection breaks, at which point it returns to main and continue gets called, skipping the fork stuff and starting the process over again. So does the fork stuff ever get executed?

What you're describing is the behavior if `forkflg` is zero.

The `fork` is called *if* `forkflg` is set. Note that, in that case, `docomm` is called in the *child* and *not* the parent (because `fork` returned 0). So, the *parent* will *not* be blocked while the child does the echoing.

Thus, the *parent* returns immediately and is free to do the `waitpid` loop to reap any old children and restart the main/outer loop.

The `waitpid` loop only happens when a new connection comes in, so several children may have already terminated and will stay in zombie state until the `waitpid` loop gets executed [which will reap any/multiple pending children].

A cleaner way to reap the children *might* be to set up a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` and have it do the `waitpid` loop. This would reap all spent children immediately, *without* having to wait for a new connection to roll in.

Or, with the signal handler, add the `waitpid` loop to `listening` [inside the current loop] because if a `SIGCHLD` signal comes in, `accept` will return immediately with `errno` set to `EINTR`

Comment: Thank you!!!  Just from a glance:
1) Can I ask why you created a fork flag if you never change the value of it?  Should it be changed somewhere?

Comment: 2) Just tracing through the program mentally, it seems like the forking section will never be executed.  Correct me where I'm wrong: after initially setting the socket to listen, the while loop will enter, and `listening()` will be called.  Execution will halt in `listening()` until a connection is accepted.  Control will return to main, where `docomm()` gets called.  Control stays in `docomm()` until the connection breaks, at which point it returns to main and `continue` gets called, skipping the fork stuff and starting the process over again.  So does the fork stuff ever get executed?

Comment: Ohhh, I see now.  So this way, I can change it to multiprocess if I want, or keep it the way it was.  Nice.  Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, here's a recent answer of mine that is similar to what you've been doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530184/over-tcp-communication-in-c-how-can-you-indicate-to-stop-calling-read-for-a-r/53530491#53530491

Comment: To the DVer, why the DV?